# Get object type from optional?

Tags: swift

Is it possible to get the object type from an optional?

For example, if I have a class that has a property that is an optional string, can I somehow just get back the string type?

The exact use case I have is I have many custom classes all of which have a property that is storing another custom class as an optional value. I would like to write a generic function that will create an instance of the object class stored in the optional.

Here is an example of what I am looking for, although .dynamicType does not work since it is an optional:

```
class Class1 {
}

class Class2 {
    var myOp: Class1?
}

var c = Class2()
c.myOp = c.myOp.dynamicType()
```

Comment: any questions about my answer?

Comment: Haven't gotten to look through and examine it as much as I'd like yet. At work at the moment. Hope to take a closer look at it tonight.

Comment: Looks very detailed though. Thank you for taking the time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you wanted to use this with Generics I tried it for you. It works, but it may not be so useful.

**First some setup:**

This is a helper protocol to make sure our Generic type will have a known init method.

```
protocol ZeroParameterInit {
    init()
}
```

---

This is an extension to get the type from an optional:

```
extension Optional {

    var dynamicWrappedType : Wrapped.Type {
        return Wrapped.self
    }
}
```

---

**Implemented in your code:**

```
class Class1 : ZeroParameterInit {
    required init() {}
}

class Class2 {
    var myOp: Class1?
}

var c = Class2()
c.myOp = c.myOp.dynamicWrappedType.init()
```

---

**Generic implementation:**

```
class Class1 : ZeroParameterInit {
    required init() {}
}

class Class2<T where T : ZeroParameterInit> {
    var attribute: Optional<T>// used long syntax to remind you of : Optional<Wrapped>
    init(attr:T) {
        attribute = attr
        attribute = nil
    }
}
```

---

The function to create the instance:

```
func myFunc<T>(instance: Class2<T>) -> T {

    return instance.attribute.dynamicWrappedType.init()

}
```

---

Some tests:

```
let alpha = Class1()
let beta = Class2(attr: alpha)
beta.attribute = myFunc(beta)
```

---

**The issue:**

You can't create an instance of `Class2` without informing it about the type of it's generic attribute. So you need to pass it some object/type and that complicates things again.

---

**Some extra methods that might improve how it all works:**

```
init() {
}

let delta = Class2<Class1>()
delta.attribute = myFunc(delta)
```

---

```
init(type:T.Type) {
}

let epsilon = Class2(type: Class1.self)
epsilon.attribute = myFunc(epsilon)
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you. The extension portion is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to check if the optional exist:

```
func myFunc(c: Class2) -> Class1? {
    if let c1 = c.myOp{
      return c1.dynamicType()
    }
    return nil
}
```

OR

```
 func myFunc(c: Class2) -> Class1? {
        if c.myOp != nil{
          return c.myOp!.dynamicType()
        }
        return nil
    }
```

Note the your return type need to be optional as well.

Comment: The trick is, it is going to be nil. I am actually going to be creating an instance of the object type to store in that property. This is why I am hoping to be able to get it from the optional data type itself rather than the value being stored.

Comment: Your code won't compile at line `return c1.dynamicType()` It will say `Initializing from a meta type value must reference 'init' explicitly`

Answer (score 0):

Tried this in simulator, seems like doing the right thing, if I understood you

```
class Class1 {
}

class Class2 {
    var myOp: Class1?
}

func myFunc(c: Class2) -> AnyObject {
    if let c1 = c.myOp{
        return c1.self
    }
    return c
}

var object = Class2()
object.myOp = Class1()
myFunc(object) // Class1
```

Comment: What I need it to do is more along the lines of if you change the final two lines to this instead: object.myOp = myFunc(object)